# Binding string to ng-repeat item value with matching name

Tags: angularjs

This list sets the value of `abc` according to the item clicked.

```
<ul>
    <li><a ng-click="abc = 'score'">Score</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="abc = 'count'">Count</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="abc = 'average'">Average</a></li>
</ul>
```

`List.items` contains values that correspond to `score`, `count` and `average`. Items are ordered by the value of `abc`.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in list.items | orderBy:'-' + abc">
        {{ 'item.' + abc }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

My only problem is this line: `{{ 'item.' + abc }}`

How do I bind the value of `{{ item.score }}`, `{{ item.count }}` or `{{ item.average }}` based on the value of `abc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[]` object notation when object properties are variables. This is standard javascript practice

```
 {{ item[abc] }}
```